# SQL Server Agent Job for the first 4 days of Month

Tags: sql-server-2000

I was wondering if anyone knew how to create a job that will run the first 4 days of the month in SQL Server 2000? I found how to run a job once on the first or second day, but the only way I figured I could run each of the four days would be to create a job for each day meaning I would have 4 jobs created. I was hoping for a better way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of creating 4 jobs, you can create one job with 4 schedules.

Fire up enterprise manager, create your job as you normally would and on the schedules tab of the Job properties add 4 schedules, one for each day of the month you'd like the job to run.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I don;t have SQL 2000 to hand but can you not once the job is created add 4x schedules to the job (Edit Job > New Schedule or similar)

Sorry if this isn't available, you can use this method in 2008

he he, As Jason says